# Monitoring a k8s custom resource state

Tags: prometheus, kube-state-metrics

How can I monitor status of a Kubernetes custom resource? I have a CRD that I can check with "kubectl get myresource" and it reports a "ready" status. I would like to have this as a metric in Prometheus.

I've followed this document, but for some reason, the metric is not showing up: https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/main/docs/customresourcestate-metrics.md

If there is a better/other way to do it than via kube-state-metrics, I'll be interested to check it out.

Comment: I am also working on exposing custom metrics with kube-state-metrics, and I think it's the right way. Could you share: the CRD, the custom metric defintion, and the ouput of curl to your kube state metrics service '/metrics' endpoint (removing standard metrics)